# memory-leak caused by filling vector

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I got a memory-leak, caused by a function convert.
The function converts a very big vector of 3D-pointdata to another
vector of other 3D-pointdata.

here is my code:

IPoint3D.h

```
struct IPoint3D
{
    virtual ~IPoint3D()
    {
    }

    float x, y, z;
    virtual std::string toString() = 0;
};
```

RealSenseCamera.h

```
class RealSenseCamera : public IRealSenseCamera 
{
public:
    RealSenseCamera();
    ~RealSenseCamera();

    CameraInitializationResult CreateSession(int width, int height, int fps) override;
    SetSensorConfigurationResult SetSensorConfiguration(pxcBool dsAutoExposure, pxcBool dsCropping, pxcI32 dsGain, pxcI32 laserPower, PXCCapture::Device::IVCAMAccuracy accuracy) override;

    bool IsReady() override;
    int GetFrameSize() override;
    void Destroy() override;
    std::vector<IPoint3D*> QueryVertices() override;

private:
    int _width, _height, _fps;
    PXCSession* _session;
    PXCSenseManager* _senseManager;
    PXCProjection* _projection;
    PXCCapture::Device* _device;

    std::vector<IPoint3D*> convert(std::vector<PXCPoint3DF32> source);
};
```

RealSenseCamera.cpp

```
RealSenseCamera::RealSenseCamera() : _width(0), _height(0), _fps(0), _session(nullptr), _senseManager(nullptr), _projection(nullptr), _device(nullptr)
{
}

RealSenseCamera::~RealSenseCamera()
{
}

CameraInitializationResult RealSenseCamera::CreateSession(int width, int height, int fps)
{
    _width = width;
    _height = height;
    _fps = fps;

    _session = PXCSession::CreateInstance();
    if (_session == nullptr)
        return CameraInitializationResult(false, "Failed to create camera session instance.");

    _senseManager = _session->CreateSenseManager();

    if (_senseManager == nullptr)
        return CameraInitializationResult(false, "Failed to create SenseManager.");

    _senseManager->EnableStream(PXCCapture::STREAM_TYPE_DEPTH, width, height, fps);
    _senseManager->Init();

    PXCCaptureManager* captureManager = _senseManager->QueryCaptureManager();

    if (captureManager == nullptr)
        return CameraInitializationResult(false, "Failed to create CaptureManager.");

    _device = captureManager->QueryDevice();

    if (_device == nullptr)
        return CameraInitializationResult(false, "Failed to create device.");

    return CameraInitializationResult(true, "Initialization successful.");
}

bool RealSenseCamera::IsReady()
{
    return _session != nullptr && _device != nullptr && _senseManager != nullptr && _senseManager->IsConnected();
}

int RealSenseCamera::GetFrameSize()
{
    return _width * _height;
}

SetSensorConfigurationResult RealSenseCamera::SetSensorConfiguration(pxcBool autoExposure, pxcBool cropping, pxcI32 gain, pxcI32 laserPower, PXCCapture::Device::IVCAMAccuracy accuracy)
{
    if (_device == nullptr)
        return SetSensorConfigurationResult(false, "Failed to find device.");

        _device->SetDSLeftRightAutoExposure(autoExposure);
        _device->SetDSLeftRightCropping(cropping);
        _device->SetDSLeftRightGain(gain);
        _device->SetIVCAMLaserPower(laserPower);
        _device->SetIVCAMAccuracy(accuracy);

        return SetSensorConfigurationResult(true, "New Configuration ist set.");
}

std::vector<IPoint3D*> RealSenseCamera::QueryVertices()
{
    std::vector<PXCPoint3DF32> vertices;

    if (_senseManager->AcquireFrame(true) >= pxcStatus::PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR) {

        PXCCapture::Sample* _sample = _senseManager->QuerySample();
        PXCImage* depthImage = _sample->depth;

        vertices.resize(_width * _height);

        _projection = _device->CreateProjection();
        _projection->QueryVertices(depthImage, &vertices[0]);
    }

    _senseManager->ReleaseFrame();

    // konvertierung leider bisher nötig
    return convert(vertices);
}

// Neuer vector wird für Punktdaten angelegt
std::vector<IPoint3D*> RealSenseCamera::convert(std::vector<PXCPoint3DF32> source)
{
    int size = GetFrameSize();
    std::vector<IPoint3D*> target(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        target[i] = new PXCPoint3DF32Adapter(source[i]);
    }

    return target;
}

void RealSenseCamera::Destroy()
{
    if (_device != nullptr)
        _device->Release();


    if (_senseManager != nullptr)
    {
        _senseManager->Close();
        _senseManager->Release();
    }

    if (_session != nullptr)
        _session->Release();
}
```

Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: Why do you think you have a memory leak here? What investigation is already done by you and what results achieved?

Comment: I used the debugger of visual studio that shows me my processmemory over time. After 2 minutes i got a leak of more than 10gb.

Comment: I thought its maybe the old pointerdata in the vertices-vector thats not been deleted. (sorry fo my bad english)

Comment: As written, the code that receives the vector from `QueryVertices` needs to `delete` its elements. I would consider using "smart" pointers.

Comment: IOW, The allocations done with `target[i] = new PXCPoint3DF32Adapter(source[i]);` in the `convert` method has no corresponding `delete` anywhere in the presented code, including the destructor of `RealSenseCamera`. That makes it *highly* suspect as a memory leak. Smart pointers are likely a good fit for this, unless you can completely eliminate the manually-managed dynamic allocation.

Comment: If your `vector` owns `IPoint3D*` use [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of raw pointer. It will automatically delete the managed object.

Comment: Thanks, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IPoint3D>>` solves my problem.